# How to implement 2 parameter, and how QueryRow to implementing parameter SequenceID and MobilePhone

Tags: go

I have a problem with implementing 2 parameters like this: `http://localhost:8080/SMSBlast/SequenceID?SequenceID=2&MobilePhone=85261415223`

How to query with two columns `SequenceID` and `MobilePhone` to get `SequenceID=2&MobilePhone=85261415223`, I have tried many ways but still not working

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    db, err :=  sql.Open("sqlserver","sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS&connection+timeout=30")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }


    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    type SMSBlast struct {
        SequenceID  int
        MobilePhone string
        Output  string
        WillBeSentDate *time.Time
        SentDate *time.Time
        Status *string
        DtmUpd *time.Time
    }

    router := gin.Default()

    //Get a SMSBlast  detail
    router.POST("/SMSBlast/:SequenceID", func(context *gin.Context) {
        var(
            smsblast SMSBlast
            result gin.H
        )

    SequenceID := context.Param("SequenceID")
    MobilePhone := context.Param("MobilePhone")

        err := db.QueryRow("SELECT SequenceID,MobilePhone,Output,WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd FROM  SMSBlast2 Where SequenceID = ? AND MobilePhone = ? "+SequenceID , MobilePhone).Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)
        //fmt.Println(row)
        fmt.Println(err)
        //err = row.Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)

        if err != nil{
            //if no results send null
            result = gin.H{
                "result": nil,
                "count":  0,
            }
            }else{
                result = gin.H{
                    "result" : smsblast,
                    "count" : 1,
                }
            }

        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT SequenceID,MobilePhone,Output,WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd FROM  SMSBlast2 Where SequenceID = $1 AND MobilePhone = $2", SequenceID, MobilePhone).Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd)
```

EDIT:

The query includes placeholders enumerated as `$1`, `$2`, etc. These placeholders are for the variables you include as parameters. In your comment you replaced `$1` with `$3`. That is not how it works. Leave it as `$1`, store the value in the `SequenceID` variable and pass that variable to `QueryRow`.

Here is a simplified example to illustrate:

```
SequenceID := 3
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM SMSBlast2 WHERE SequenceID = $1", SequenceID).Scan(...)
```

Now with two parameters:

```
SequenceID := 3
MobilePhone := "85261415223"
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM SMSBlast2 WHERE SequenceID = $1 AND MobilePhone = $2", SequenceID, MobilePhone).Scan(...)
```

Comment: yes correct  with err := db.QueryRow("SELECT SequenceID,MobilePhone,Output,WillBeSentDate, SentDate, Status, DtmUpd FROM  SMSBlast2 Where SequenceID = $3 AND MobilePhone = $85261415223 ",SequenceID, MobilePhone).Scan(&smsblast.SequenceID, &smsblast.MobilePhone, &smsblast.Output, &smsblast.WillBeSentDate, &smsblast.SentDate, &smsblast.Status, &smsblast.DtmUpd) , but I want select SequenceID  & MobilePhone in URL not in code to select SequenceID  & MobilePhone

Comment: You misunderstand the syntax, I've edited my answer. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Query()` instead, example [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#another-example-query--post-form):

```golang
SequenceID := context.Query("SequenceID")
MobilePhone := context.Query("MobilePhone")
```